# Passing array into query string

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I need to send array as query parameter, I do it like this

```
StringBuilder Ids = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < array.Count; i++)
{
    Ids.Append(String.Format("&id[{0}]={1}", i, items[i].ID));
}
                    
ifrDocuments.Attributes.Add("src", "Download.aspx?arrayCount=" + array.Count + Ids);
```

After this I have string:

```
Download.aspx?arrayCount=8&id[0]=106066&id[1]=106065&id[2]=106007&id[3]=105284&id[4]=105283&id[5]=105235&id[6]=105070&id[7]=103671
```

It can contain 100 elements and in this case I'm getting error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJdmE.png)

Maybe I can do it in another way? Not by sending it inside query qtring.

Comment: ...that depends if the site you're accessing allows other parameter types. and therefore is something we can't answer - consult the documentation, or contact whoever is responsible for the site.

Comment: I think if it's possible for you and querysting is limited, it's better to pass sit through form's post or multipart form post in case of large data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a limit on URL length on multiple levels (browsers, proxy servers, etc). You can change maxQueryString (*1) but I would not recommend it if you expect real users to use your system.

It looks like downloads.aspx is your page. Put all those ids in temporary storage - (cache or database) and pass the key to this new entity in the request

*1: https://blog.elmah.io/fix-max-url-and-query-string-length-with-web-config-and-iis/

Answer (score 0):

QueryString is not the way to pass an array because of the limits.
If you have hands on the endpoint, you should consider sending your array in a POST Body.

Regards